# Why does browser not use cache even when Cache-Control/Expires headers are set for static files?

Tags: http, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

I have implemented caching on my webserver for static files like images. I've tried setting **response headers** such as:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=864000
Expires: Mon, 21 Aug 2018 14:00:00 GMT
```

This will at least cache the files for one day. But using the Developer Tools, I can see the requests still being fetched without caching.

The browser seems to send **request headers** like:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Even though I explicitly instruct it from my webserver not to do that.

Comment: And you don’t by any chance have the dev tools option _not_ to use the cache, but always request the resources fresh from the server, activated …?

Comment: @CBroe Exactly that! But it was very hard to find - couldn't find similar questions, so I figured I'll put it on here. I am unfamiliar with the webserver I am currently using, so I figured I incorrectly configured the caching stuff. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, when you have Developer Tools open, the browser actually sends `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the request as a supposedly "useful feature" since you are probably debugging.

By default this feature is enabled. In FireFox this feature can be found listed below the 'Advanced settings' in the settings-menu (use the gear icon) as: **Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)**

Uncheck that feature, and caching should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you are developing a web application using **Visual Studio** (e.g. ASP.net MVC) and you use **Chrome** for running your application, Chrome will **always** send header **`Cache-Control: no-cache`**. No matter whether you `Disable HTTP Cache`. Also closing the `Developer Tools` does not help.

What does help: Use another browser for debugging or start a new instance of Chrome.